# NullPointException en Intent kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, nullpointerexception

estoy realizando un servicio de notificaciones con Kotlin y Android Studio. El problema es que me da un error que me indica que las variables del `Intent` son nulas. Aqui os dejo el error:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.listadetareas, PID: 2081
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.listadetareas.ServicioNotificacion@c6c0c4 with Intent { cmp=com.example.listadetareas/.ServicioNotificacion (has extras) }: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3491)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(Unknown Source:0)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.listadetareas.ServicioNotificacion.onStartCommand(ServicioNotificacion.kt:54)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3474)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(Unknown Source:0) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Clase AñadirTarea(La cual envia los elementos en el intent)

```kotlin
    val titulo_añadir_tarea = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.titulo_añadir_tarea).text
    val descripcion_añadir_tarea = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.descripcion_añadir_tarea).text
        btn_añadir_tarea.setOnClickListener {
            val hora_añadir_tarea = sp_hora.selectedItem.toString()
            val minuto_añadir_tarea = sp_minuto.selectedItem.toString()

            if (titulo_añadir_tarea.isNotEmpty() && descripcion_añadir_tarea.isNotEmpty() && hora_añadir_tarea != null && minuto_añadir_tarea != null) {


                val db = DB(applicationContext);
                try {
                    db.añadirTarea(applicationContext, titulo_añadir_tarea.toString(), descripcion_añadir_tarea.toString(), dia, hora_añadir_tarea, minuto_añadir_tarea )
                    val intentdatostarea = Intent(this, ServicioNotificacion::class.java)

                    intentdatostarea.putExtra("titulo", titulo_añadir_tarea)
                    intentdatostarea.putExtra("descripcion", descripcion_añadir_tarea)
                    intentdatostarea.putExtra("año", recuperar_year)
                    intentdatostarea.putExtra("mes", recuperar_month)
                    intentdatostarea.putExtra("dia", recuperar_day)
                    intentdatostarea.putExtra("hora", hora_añadir_tarea)
                    intentdatostarea.putExtra("minuto", minuto_añadir_tarea)
                    startService(intentdatostarea)
                    //val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                    //startActivity(intent)

                //val notificar = Notificacion(applicationContext)
                    //notificar.crearNotificacion("prueba", "prueba")


                } catch (e: Exception){
                    Log.d("Error añadirTarea: ", e.toString())
                }


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Ha habido un error al crear la tarea $descripcion_añadir_tarea", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
```

La clase de mi servicio (Clase que recibe el intent):

```kotlin
    package com.example.listadetareas

    import android.app.Service
    import android.content.Intent
    import android.os.Handler
    import android.os.IBinder
    import android.widget.Toast
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
    import java.util.Date


    class ServicioNotificacion : Service() {

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null;
    }

    fun fechaamilisegundos(titulo: String, description: String, año: Int, mes: Int, dia: Int, hora: Int, minuto: Int): Long {
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")

        val firstDate = sdf.parse("$dia/$mes/$año $hora:$minuto")

        val actualDateformat = sdf.format(Date())
        val actualDate = sdf.parse(actualDateformat)

        val diff = firstDate.time - actualDate.time
        if (diff <= 0 || titulo.isNullOrEmpty() || description.isNullOrEmpty()){
            return -1
        } else{
            return diff
        }

    }


    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        val titulo = intent!!.getStringExtra("titulo")
        val descripcion = intent.getStringExtra("descripcion")
        val año = intent.getStringExtra("año").toInt()
        val mes = intent.getStringExtra("mes").toInt()
        val dia = intent.getStringExtra("dia").toInt()
        val hora = intent.getStringExtra("hora").toInt()
        val minuto = intent.getStringExtra("minuto").toInt()


        val difffechaenmilis = fechaamilisegundos(titulo, descripcion, año, mes, dia, hora, minuto)
        var correctoerror: Int? = null
        if (difffechaenmilis.equals(-1)){
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Ha introducido una fecha no valida, por favor, revisela e intentelo de nuevo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            correctoerror = 0
        } else{
            val runner = Runnable {
                val notifier = Notificacion(this) // Linea 54 que da el error
                notifier.crearNotificacion(titulo!!, descripcion!!)
            }
            val handler = Handler()
            handler.postDelayed(runner,difffechaenmilis)
            correctoerror = START_STICKY
        }
        return correctoerror

    }
    }
```

Clase Notificacion

```
class Notificacion(val context: Context) {
private val CHANNELID: String = "CanalTareas"

init {
    createNotificationChannel()
}

private fun createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val name = context.getString(R.string.titulo_notif)
        val descriptionText = context.getString(R.string.descripcion_notif)
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNELID, name, importance).apply {
            description = descriptionText
        }
        // Register the channel with the system
        val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
            context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}
fun Random.nextInt(range: IntRange): Int {
    return range.start + nextInt(range.last - range.start)
}
fun crearNotificacion(title: String, descripcion: String) {
    var builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNELID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(descripcion)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
    with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)) {
        // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
        notify(Random().nextInt(1..100000000), builder.build())
    }
}
```

}

No entiendo que puede hacer que titulo sea null, ¿veis algun fallo? Gracias de antemano

Comment: puedes poner `Notificacion`?

Comment: Definitivamente la clase Notificacion es el problema por el cual no se recibe el objeto con los datos, agrega la clase Notificacion por favor.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich Puesto

Comment: @Jorgesys añadido

Comment: @Angel ya vi el problema, revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se genera al tratar de crear la notificación con valores null.

Similar a una Activity, **en un Servicio los datos que envías deben ser recibidos dentro de `onCreate()` ya que si intentas obtenerlos en otro método siempre tendrán valores null.**

Dentro de `onCreate()` debes recibir los valores y crea tu notificación:

```
   class ServicioNotificacion : Service() {
    
      override fun onCreate() {
        val titulo = intent!!.getStringExtra("titulo")
        val descripcion = intent.getStringExtra("descripcion")
        val año = intent.getStringExtra("año").toInt()
        val mes = intent.getStringExtra("mes").toInt()
        val dia = intent.getStringExtra("dia").toInt()
        val hora = intent.getStringExtra("hora").toInt()
        val minuto = intent.getStringExtra("minuto").toInt()


        val difffechaenmilis = fechaamilisegundos(titulo, descripcion, año, mes, dia, hora, minuto)
   
        if (difffechaenmilis.equals(-1)){
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Ha introducido una fecha no valida, por favor, revisela e intentelo de nuevo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
   
        } else{
            val runner = Runnable {
                val notifier = Notificacion(this) 
                notifier.crearNotificacion(titulo!!, descripcion!!)
            }
            val handler = Handler()
            handler.postDelayed(runner,difffechaenmilis)
   
        }
   
      }
    
   }
```